# AllowAnonymous for elmah

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

when I go to https://site/elmah it will redirect me to the login page, i do not want this, Anonymous user also may go here. (but only on this server and not remote! )

**details**

Its a MVC 4 website with formsauthentication. I added a filter so i do not have to put [Authorize] on my controllers

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

**web.config**

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="?"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="?"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah"/>
 <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="5"/>
 </authentication>
....
</system.web>
```